# Return object as ember-model with matching key in array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

What I'm trying to accomplish is to return only one object to the model and loop through it's properties in a handlebars template. Thanx-a-Lot for any help!

My response looks like this:

```
{"U+554A":{
    "id":1,
   "unihex":"U+554A",
   "num_reference":"&#21621;",
   "totalStrokes":10,
   "kMandarin":"a\n",
   "kDefinition":"exclamatory particle\n"},
 "U+611B":{
   "id":2,
   "unihex":"U+611B",
   "num_reference":"&#24859;",
   "totalStrokes":13,
   "kMandarin":"\u00c3\u00a0i\n",
   "kDefinition":"love, be fond of, like\n"}
}
```

I tried everything. The most obvious being these two, just as a tryout, but the ember inspector shows no model is set:

```
    var sinograms = Ember.$.getJSON(apiurl);
    return sinograms['U+554A'];
```

I also tried:

```
    var sinograms = Ember.$.getJSON(apiurl);
    return sinograms[0];
```

NB:
I can change the response format if necessary.
I know it works when I loose the object-keys (without "U+554A"), but then how do I select the matching character.

@abuani: Upon your request. Thanx btw.

```
//app.js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
this.resource('signup');
this.resource('login');
this.resource('profile');
this.resource('overview');
this.resource('practice');
});

App.OverviewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    var url = 'http://localhost/~hiufung/RoadToChinese/index.php/api/sinograms/random?limit=2';
    var sinograms = Ember.$.getJSON(url);
    return sinograms;
}
});

//index.html (inline template)
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="overview">
    <header class="bar bar-nav">
        <a class="icon icon-left pull-left" href="back"></a>        
            <h1 class="title">RoadToChinese</h1>
        <a id="showRightPush" class="icon icon-gear pull-right" href="overview-settings"></a>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-padded">
            {{#each object in model}}
            <p>{{object.num_reference}}<p>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't add a comment to your initial question, but can you please post a few other pieces of code:

The router that's loading this(I imagine this is being done in your model function), the setupController if you have one, and the template that's trying to render the object. Without this information, there's little I can do to help.

EDIT Since there's code:

I should have noticed, your model is return an objects when Ember expects the model to be an array of objects. The first thing you should do is make the return from the server an Array. If you don't have control over this, then you can change your model to return

```
return Ember.A([sinograms]);
```

And that should work.

After that though, you can remove the nested object within each object. If you don't remove that, then you also need to make the inner objects an Array so you can iterate over it.

Let me know how this goes.

Here's the [JSBIN](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xipol/5/)

Comment: Added some more code. The controller is automatically instantiated by ember, so no code (yet). I don't think it has anything to do with the template. I checked the response-format in JSONlint and it's valid JSON. However, might it be that the response is missing square-brackets, [] to be treated as an array?
Tnx.

Comment: Ah yes! That's it. First thing you need to do is wrap the content into an array. Ember expects the models to be an array of objects. After you change the response to be an array of objects, you can probably take out the initial "U+554A" definition. That's unnecessary as you have unique ids already.

Comment: Ok, then what is a logical way in ember to find and display a specific object I want? I want to show one object at the time. So I figured I'd just do some logic in the model where I select which has object has some matching property unihex ='U+554A'. That's why I added the initial "U+554A" keys in the first place, so I could select the right object out of the response.
The only thing that really worked till now is losing the "U+554A"keys. The {{#each}} then works. Tnx again.

Comment: Ahh so that's a different type of question! So unless you're modeling the objects, I try to stay away from "object_type" : [ object ], for numerous reasons. However, since you HAVE the unihex key within the objects themsleves, there's a nifty way of accessing these properties in the controller. Ember has a computed property, and you can set a property like UniHex: Ember.computed.filterBy('content.unihex','some_value');           If you want more information on this, I'll set up a JSBin. Once you set up the computed property on the controller, you can iterate it over like anything else.

Comment: Thanx very much for the example, but why wouldn't that work with 'U+554A'keys? In sum: somewhere I need some logic to select just one object out of the array of objects to display the right one. I read something about computed properties. I definately have to do some more reading, any help is more than welcome. Tnx again.
Update: I just read ur comment after posting this.. a JSBin would be great!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/xipol/41/ You can see there you can filter by the content and the property, then you have an optional flag which is equality. I've only recently started getting into computed properties, but they're great!

Comment: Wow. That's actually a pretty nice solution. The whole reason for me adding those initial keys was to avoid iterating with a for-loop..
I guess case solved, ghèhehe. Thanx-a-Lot!
PS: I just got into Ember.js, so I'm still figuring out what code to put where.. I only have experience with backend MVC frameworks.

Comment: No issues, I would still consider myself relatively new. From what I've seen in the past, try to include the route, controller, model and templates relating to your problem. Once you state your issue, try to provide as much relevant information as possible. Definitely look into the computer properties! They're real cool.

Comment: Hi albuani, I was hoping you might know how to set up a computed property with a variable as parameter?
Building further on your JSBin example, this doesn't work:
`App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sinogram: 'U+611B',
    particularHex : Ember.computed.filterBy('content' , 'unihex',  this.get('sinogram'))
})`